# Timer using 'moment-timer'

Tags: node.js, timer, node-modules, stopwatch

I need to create a timer countdown inside the server. I find 'moment-timer' the plugin of moment.js. The reference doesn't show how to import it in node, so I import it like this:

```
var moment = require('moment-timer');
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
```

The documentation doesn't explain this.

https://github.com/SeverinDK/moment-timer

I try to run a simple timer, but

```
let timer = new moment.duration(1000);
timer.start();
```

TypeError: timer.start is not a function

Someone who has works with times in nodejs. I need to measure time like as stopwatch, when I mark some variable with given value and when that value changes get the time that happens between that two events.

Answer (score 2):

This reassigns the variable with original `moment` that doesn't have `timer` method:

```
var moment = require('moment-timer');
var moment = require('moment');
```

Considering that the library is published on NPM and the documentation doesn't give any specific instructions on how it should be used, it's safe to assume that it should be required as usual:

```
let moment = require('moment-timer');
let timer = new moment.duration(1000);
```

The quickest way to settle doubts is to check [source code](https://github.com/SeverinDK/moment-timer/blob/v1.2.3/lib/moment-timer.js#L7). Indeed, it just wraps around original `moment` library and augments its functionality.